# Call command line from C program

Tags: c, command-line

I am writing an command line application in C and from within the program, I would like to call other command-line applications.  For example (and only as a clear example!), say the I would like to write a C app that calls the java compiler.  For one, how would I do this?  Is there a C function that directly calls the command line of something?  For two, how would I take the normal text output that the java compiler displays and display it through the c program?

I'm sorry if this sounds a bit crazy, but I am very new to C and I have never done anything like this before.  I would love to start writing a few of these utility style apps.  If it matters any, I am currently running Windows, but would prefer a platform-independent method if possible, as I do use Linux from time to time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might look into [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system). I think you can use it in Windows as well as UNIX/Linux systems.

Comment: thanks!  I just messed around with using system() and it does seem to be doing what I need.  Thanks!!

Comment: please note that system runs in sync (so your process would wait for child to finish), if you want async execution look into CreateProcess Windows API

Comment: @Denny Rolling: Yes, or `fork`/`exec` for UNIX/Linux.