# Upload file to google drive from raspberry pi

Tags: python, c++, c, linux, raspberry-pi

I am working on capturing image from USB Webcam using mjpg-streamer and its working fine now. For next state i wan to compress all image captured and send it to google drive but i have no idea how to do it.

Currently I am trying 1 example written in python from this [link](http://shadowbadger.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/uploading-deleting-bypassing-the-bin-and-searching-for-documents-on-google-docs-with-python-gdata/). 
When i try to upload_doc using:

```
upload_doc = client.CreateResource(doc, create_uri=create_uri, media=media)
```

I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test.py", line 38, in <module>
upload_doc = client.CreateResource(doc, create_uri=create_uri, media=media)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/docs/client.py", line 300, in create_resource
return uploader.upload_file(create_uri, entry, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/client.py", line 1085, in upload_file
start_byte, self.file_handle.read(self.chunk_size))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/client.py", line 1044, in  upload_chunk
raise error
gdata.client.RequestError: Server responded with: 400,
```

**[EDIT]** I was able to upload a zip file to google drive, sorry for my silly mistake. I didn't stated the right path for the folder.

```
DOC_TITLE='a.jpg.tar'
LOCAL_FILE='/home/Desktop/webserver-cam/a.jpg.tar'
doc = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type='document', title=DOC_TITLE)
media = gdata.data.MediaSource()
media.SetFileHandle(LOCAL_FILE, 'application/octet-stream')
create_uri = gdata.docs.client.RESOURCE_UPLOAD_URI + '?convert=false'
upload_doc = client.CreateResource(doc, create_uri=create_uri, media=media)
```

Answer (score 0):

For compressing the file you can use command line interface of for example winrar. Example: `rar a -r yourfiles.rar *.txt c:\yourfolder`. Just call the commands through your application by using for example [system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342209/call-command-line-from-c-program).

Comment: ya i know how to compress but i have no idea how to deal to google thingy!